# How to fetch all the data in mssql having a multiple server name by using Php And MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I have module where I need to create a cron job in php, but first thing I need to do is to fetch all the data on the table on every each server name, so now the twist here is we have a lot of server but same database. so is it possible to get all the data in every server name on the same time,

We have **60 Plus server name** but I don't know how can i figure out to set up the connection.
For the mean time my setting will be.

**Login:sa**

**Password:1234**

**Servername: xx.xx.xx.xxx**

I already create a sample program but this program the only i can fetch is one server only.

```
<?php 



            $serverNames = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress", "xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress"];//serverName\instanceName

            foreach($serverNames as $ip) {

                $ip_array = $ip;

                $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"users", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"1234");
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $ip_array, $connectionInfo);

                if( $conn ) {       
                }else{
                     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
                     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
            }

            $tsql = "SELECT * FROM users";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);

            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['LastName'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['DateBirth'].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';


            }


        ?>
```

**Goal: How to fetch the data in multiple server**

Thank you

Comment: If you have multiple database servers, then you will have to make a connection to each one of them.

Comment: unless you have them all configured as Linked Servers in SQL Server, and could then do a UNION query, you will have to instead do a loop in PHP where you connect to each one individually, run the query and echo the results. I can't imagine how you ended up with 60 databases with identical tables in them?? What on earth is the scenario for that? P.S. **Please** don't log into your server as `sa` from an application, that's a nasty security risk. Use a SQL login specifically for the purpose, which only has the permissions it actually needs.

Comment: *"I can't imagine how you ended up with 60 databases with identical tables in them??"* Considering the OP's code says they are using Express, I wonder if it's "misuse" of the Express Edition; rather than upgrading to a paid version of application, @ADyson .

Comment: @ADyson yah, sa account is just an sample, do you mean for that i need to loop each server name?

Comment: Yes I do mean that. Put all the server names in an array, loop through the array and run your existing code inside the loop, changing the server name each time for the current array entry.

Comment: But please...tell us how you ended up in this situation with so many databases to begin with? Perhaps there is a better way to organise your data, and avoid this problem completely.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for that, i give you small description.  this database is came from on our third party, so they create that database on each stores, so we have 60+ stores so the third party they create server name on each stores. that's why there are alot of servers

Comment: @ADyson can you give me sample what do you mean put all the server name in array?

Comment: Like this: `$servers = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress", "yy.yy.yy.yyy\\sqlexpress", "zz.zz.zz.zz\\sqlexpress"];`. i.e. a simple PHP array like any other. Then you can use a `foreach` loop to read each item in the array.

Comment: @ADyson after i make the data in array, it shows sqlsrv_connect() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: What exactly did you do? You aren't supposed pass the **whole array** into sqlsrv_connect, you have to pass one item **from** the array, each time you loop. Do you understand how to use an array and loop through it? https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: hi @ADyson please see my update on my post. so what i did.

Comment: @ADyson the only that i get is the last data. the first server is not joining.

Comment: Well of course, because you ended the loop before you execute your query! So the query still only runs once. The **whole code** needs to run inside the loop, so that you can do the same task repeatedly for each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest attempt has a simple logical error - you end your `foreach` loop too early. All the loop does is open each connection. The query happens after the loop has finished, meaning it will only run once, and will only get data from the last database you connected to. Move the end of the loop after all of your code, and you should get the result you expect:

```
<?php 
    $serverNames = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress", "xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress"];//serverName\instanceName

    foreach($serverNames as $ip) {

        $ip_array = $ip;

        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"users", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"1234");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $ip_array, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn ) {       
        }else{
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        $tsql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['LastName'].'</td>';
            echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['DateBirth'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```